# Java Client OCSP throws "Could not determine revocation status"

Tags: java, ssl, ocsp

I am try to enable OCSP checking on the client side of a mutual TLS connection. If I enable on server-side only then the server will correctly validate the client certificate.

When I enable on the client side with the following parameters:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="$ROOTDIR/certs/intermediate/certs/local-truststore.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<some-password> -Djava.security.debug="certpath ocsp" -Djavax.net.debug="all" -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=true -Docsp.enable=true
```

then client throws the error:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Could not determine revocation status
```

Looking at the ocsp certpath debug trace and through a variety of different scenarios, it appears that somehow the OCSP validator is treating the CA certificates as "bad" (see the certpath: RejectKeySelector.match: bad key line below).

```
certpath: ForwardBuilder.getMatchingCerts()...
certpath: ForwardBuilder.getMatchingEECerts()...
certpath: X509CertSelector.match(SN: 1000
  Issuer: CN=root-ca.acme.com, O="Acme Corp, LLC", ST=New York, C=US
  Subject: CN=intermediate-ca.acme.com, O="Acme Corp, LLC", ST=New York, C=US)
certpath: X509CertSelector.match: subject DNs don't match
certpath: X509CertSelector.match(SN: 1003
  Issuer: CN=intermediate-ca.acme.com, O="Acme Corp, LLC", ST=New York, C=US
  Subject: CN=ledger.acme.com, O="Acme Corp, LLC", ST=New York, C=US)
certpath: X509CertSelector.match: subject DNs don't match
certpath: ForwardBuilder.getMatchingCACerts()...
certpath: ForwardBuilder.getMatchingCACerts(): the target is a CA
certpath: X509CertSelector.match(SN: f9e9243278f85e6a21408510cbedf46d8f0333
  Issuer: CN=root-ca.acme.com, O="Acme Corp, LLC", ST=New York, C=US
  Subject: CN=root-ca.acme.com, O="Acme Corp, LLC", ST=New York, C=US)
certpath: X509CertSelector.match returning: true
**certpath: RejectKeySelector.match: bad key**
certpath: X509CertSelector.match(SN: 1000
  Issuer: CN=root-ca.acme.com, O="Acme Corp, LLC", ST=New York, C=US
  Subject: CN=intermediate-ca.acme.com, O="Acme Corp, LLC", ST=New York, C=US)
certpath: X509CertSelector.match: subject DNs don't match
certpath: X509CertSelector.match(SN: 1003
  Issuer: CN=intermediate-ca.acme.com, O="Acme Corp, LLC", ST=New York, C=US
  Subject: CN=ledger.acme.com, O="Acme Corp, LLC", ST=New York, C=US)
certpath: X509CertSelector.match: subject DNs don't match
certpath: ForwardBuilder.getMatchingCACerts: found 0 CA certs
certpath: SunCertPathBuilder.depthFirstSearchForward(): certs.size=0
12:16:23.215 [main] ERROR app.ClientApp$ - io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

This appears to be thrown in the following JDK library code:

```
http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~vinnie/8019627/webrev.00/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/certpath/RevocationChecker.java
```

The exact certificate changes based on which CA is passed in a truststore, i.e. in the two tier I have in my test configuration, it would fail on root-ca when only that passed, or intermediate-ca when both passed.

Higher in the trace I see this from SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild

```
  Target Cert Constraints: RejectKeySelector: [
X509CertSelector: [
  Subject: CN=root-ca.acme.com,O=Acme Corp\, LLC,ST=New York,C=US
  matchAllSubjectAltNames flag: true
  Key Usage: KeyUsage [
  Crl_Sign
]
```

But not clear why (in this case root-ca) is added to RejectKeySelector.

What is the expected combination of certs passed from server (chain or individual) and truststore (chain or root only) that is expected to work?

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that ocsp.enable=true needs to be set in the Java security properties file not on the command line. You can create an override file and use via: -

Djava.security.properties=../java.security-client

Sadly not seeing OCSP Stapling enabled as yet in OpenJDK11 so further work required.